# wait till function execute completely to execute the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code to handle some cases if user clicked right or left button but the navigate became a mess when the user click both buttons together

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        setTimeout(LeftKeyPressed(),5000);
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39){
        setTimeout(RightKeyPressed(),5000);
    }
    });
});
```

I want to simply block any call till the first or second function completely executed

Comment: Are `LeftKeyPressed` and `RightKeyPressed` fully synchronous? 
`setTimeout(LeftKeyPressed(),5000);` would not do what you expect. It would execute `LeftKeyPressed` immediately, not with a delay of 5 secs.

Comment: what do you mean by fully synchronous? is there await/async in javascript?

Comment: Well if you have something like `$(...).animate(...)` inside of it, and you need to wait until the animation is finished.

Comment: I just ask, because `setTimeout` has no effect in your code, because you don't pass the functions, but the result of their invocation to `setTimeout` (or do you return a function by the `LeftKeyPressed` or `RightKeyPressed` call?)  . So there must be something inside `RightKeyPressed` and `LeftKeyPressed` that causes your problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var navt;
   $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(navt != null) return;
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        navt = setTimeout(function(){ LeftKeyPressed(); navt = null; },5000);
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39){
        navt = setTimeout(function(){ RightKeyPressed(); navt = null; },5000);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: not working, I use animation to flip page right and left and boolean solution isn't helpful.

Comment: @MohamedNaguib Perhaps you should have told us.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `flag` to block the unnecessary function calls like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var xKeyPressed = false;

   $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37 && !xKeyPressed) {
        setTimeout(LeftKeyPressed(),5000);
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39 !xKeyPressed){
        setTimeout(RightKeyPressed(),5000);
    }
    });

function LeftKeyPressed()
{ 
   xKeyPressed = true; 

   //Your code

   xKeyPressed = false;
}
function RightKeyPressed(){  

   xKeyPressed = true; 

   //Your code

   xKeyPressed = false;

}

});
```

Comment: while `LeftKeyPressed()` is called immediately,  the `setTimeout` has now effect, so most likely there is something within the `LeftKeyPressed`  that causes the problem e.g. some animation. At least the way you write it the `xKeyPressed` has no benefit, because the `setTimeout` has no effect to the code.

Comment: I agree.. If animations are used inside any of those functions, then setting a flag will no longer helpful.

Comment: Even if not the code should be `setTimeout(LeftKeyPressed,5000);` and not `setTimeout(LeftKeyPressed(),5000);`, otherwise there is no need of `xKeyPressed` in your example.

Comment: Yes I do use some animations to flip page right and left and it screw up the design even by using boolean

Answer (score 0):

Set a simple check if your code is running `LeftKeyPressed` or `RightKeyPressed` like this:

```
var inFunction = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37 && !inFunction) {
        inFunction = true; 
        setTimeout(LeftKeyPressed(),5000);
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 39 && !inFunction){
        inFunction = true;
        setTimeout(RightKeyPressed(),5000);
    }
    });
});

//Add this in your functions, both Left and Right variants,
function LeftKeyPressed(){
  //Do your normal stuff here
  inFunction = false;
}
```

There is other ways of doing this as well, but this is in my opinion a clear and concise way of doing it. You can potentially get [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) with this approach.

Comment: not working, I use animation to flip page right and left and boolean solution isn't working.